# Button no longer triggering form onsubmit event

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, input

I have recently started using:

```
<button type='submit'>Submit Form</button>
```

Instead of

```
<input type='submit value='Submit Form'>
```

To submit my HTML forms for the customisation value of using a button.

However, my form looks like:

```
<form class='format_form' action='add_admin_success.php' onsubmit='return validate_form();' method='POST'>
```

And I have just discovered using a button no longer make

```
onsubmit='return validate_form();'
```

have any effect. The form now submits without running **validate_form()**, where **validate_form()** is definetly defined as it works with an  tag.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing from `input` to `button` is the likely cause. Why don't you add the `onsubmit` code to the button as an `onclick`?

Comment: How would I stop it from submitting the form if the function returns false?

Comment: use `onclick='return validate_form();'` If it returns `false`, the form does not submit (just tried it).